# Stoppage ghci with list comprehension

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm new to Haskell.
Following list comprehension dose not work good. ghci stop it's output. (after type '7', ghci stop long long time.)

```
Prelude Data.Numbers.Primes> [x | x <- primes, x <= 10]
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package random-1.0.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package Numbers-0.2.1 ... linking ... done.
[2,3,5,7^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 ghci
```

Why ghci stop its working and how can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Could we see your main code(the "primes" function and others)?

Comment: @StevenDobay `Data.Numbers.Primes` is from the `primes` package, not his code.

Comment: @StevenDobay Yes. "primes" is not my code. Thank you.

Comment: @Wes I read "Generati~" but I can't fix why ghci can't work. Maybe I'm new to Haskell, so I can't understand that code. Sorry.

Comment: @shaegis yeah sorry it isn't an exact duplicate, that was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that GHCi can't know that your list of `primes` is ordered. Maybe after 1000000000000000 elements of `primes`, there comes some element that is smaller than `10`, so it must be still included in the ouput? That's why ghci only prints the first elements of the result (`[2,3,4,7`), but not the whole result. If you *only* want those, you can use `takeWhile`, which stops after it encounters a number that doesn't match the predicate:

```
> takeWhile (<= 10) primes
[2,3,5,7] -- takeWhile stops after it encounters 7, because the predicate becomes false

> filter (<= 10) primes
[2,3,5,7  -- filter cannot stop, because there might still be a number later in the list that satisfies the predicate. This is what the list comprehension does.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Key fact is that ghci does not know list of primes is ordered. Have a nice day. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `primes` contains all primes (and therefore it is an infinite list), the list comprehension won't terminated if you try to evaluate the list past the value 7. Since

```
[x | x <- primes, x <= 10]
```

is essentially the same as

```
filter (<= 10) primes
```

you would filter *all* primes whether they are lesser or equal to ten. However, you know that the primes are ordered, so you can take primes, as long as they are lesser than ten:

```
takeWhile (<= 10) primes
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I learn a new fact. Thank you again, have a nice day.